# Как вывести время в каждый новый элемент разметки

Tags: javascript

Пишу простое приложение для заметок ,и надо чтобы при создании новой заметки писалось время создания заметки, но не очень могу понять как для каждой новой заметки выводить дату в формате написанной мной функции , так как дата указывается только на первой карточке

**Код для создания карточки:**

```
const containerNote = document.querySelector('.note-container')

document.querySelector('.btn-addNote').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let displayNote = `
        <div class="card w-100 mt-5">
            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="note-date">
                    <p class="show-time text-secondary"></p>
                </div>

                <div class="checkers">
                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" class="input-focus mr-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" onclick="delNote(this)">Delete button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="w-100" style="border: 0"
                onfocus="addFocusToNote(this)" onblur="removeFocusToNote(this)"
                ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
    containerNote.innerHTML += displayNote
})
```

**Функция для вывода даты:**

```
let time = () => {
    let today = new Date()
    let day = today.getDay()
    let month = today.getMonth()
    let year = today.getFullYear()

    document.querySelector('.show-time').innerHTML = `${day}.${month}.${year}`
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const containerNote = document.querySelector('.note-container')

document.querySelector('.btn-addNote').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let displayNote = `
        <div class="card w-100 mt-5">
            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="note-date">
                    ${time()}
                </div>

                <div class="checkers">
                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" class="input-focus mr-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-del" onclick="delNote(this)">Delete button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" class="w-100" style="border: 0" onfocus="addFocusToNote(this)" onblur="removeFocusToNote(this)"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
  containerNote.innerHTML += displayNote
})

function delNote(that) {
  that.closest('div.card').remove()
}

function addFocusToNote(that) {
  that.closest('div.card').querySelector('.input-focus').checked = true
}

function removeFocusToNote(that) {
  that.closest('div.card').querySelector('.input-focus').checked = false
}

const time = () => {
  let today = new Date()
  let day = today.getDay()
  let month = today.getMonth()
  let year = today.getFullYear()

  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-addNote">+</button>

<div class="note-container"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо ,а как можно сохранить каждую заметку в которой что-то написано в localstorage, и так чтобы если удаляешь заметку после того как она загрузится из localstorage ,она из него исчезала?

Comment: можно сделать что угодно)

Answer (score 0):

Весь код не переписываю, добавляю ключевые вещи:

```js
let getTime = () => {
    let today = new Date()
    let day = today.getDay()
    let month = today.getMonth()
    let year = today.getFullYear()

    return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}

let parHtml = `<p class="show-time text-secondary">${getTime()}</p>`;

console.log(parHtml);
```